# How to execute file python script which is in while loop without interrupting it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have to execute a python script which is costantly in while loop, this is script2

```
while True:
#do something
 time.sleep(30)
```

Now I have script1 which does all the calculations and then I need to execute the script2. I have tried execfile but it didn't work and I had a lot of issues.
I don't know how to use subprocess module either.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: Why does it matter if the script is constantly in a loop? Executing a script always works the same way, no matter what that script does. Am I missing something?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. your question is very unclear, please edit it and elaborate

Comment: I think OP is asking about parallelism without knowing it. It's probably his first script locking until the second script is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `import` statement runs the code which it imports to create all the functions and classes that are defined within.
Python also allows you to do this with your own files.
try this:

```
while True:
    from file_to_execute import *
    time.sleep(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
while True:
    subprocess.call(["python", "/path/to/script2.py"])
    time.sleep(30)
```